# How to get part of an utterance that could be anything

Tags: dialogflow-es

If i have an intent like

'How much have I spent on'

that I'd like to match basically 'how much have i spent on ___________________'

where ____ could be any word or phrase.

I've been doing this sort of thing for some intents that do some fuzzy matching to determine what the user is speaking of and it works ok, but is it possible to do this in a reliable way, without requiring that a particularly specific phrase was uttered (which defeats the purpose of NLU to a degree)?

I have been looking for a keyword and assuming their "topic" is the remainder of the phrase, and it works, but seems like it will be prone to problems when the actual user doesn't say more or less what I intended.

I imagine I can reorganize to do this with a follow up intent, like "what category?"  and then treat the entire response as what I was trying to parse out, I was just looking to avoid it if there was some sort of built in support for this concept.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the right path.
You can use `@sys.any` entity to capture any word or phrase. And according to your use-case and what the intent is, you can add few variations of the sentences how much `have i spent on @sys.any` in the utterances.

You can also make use of slot-filling or some other fallback mechanism to validate the user input.

[image: expenses]

Comment: I dreamed up a new way to do some fancy inspection of the string to better guess what they were talking about, but read this in the morning and it seems like it was definitely a better way to go.

I previously wasn't using an entity based on some reasoning i've now forgotten, but it's working great this way.  In my fulfillment I still apply the scoring mechanism to determine what they were talking about.